# Cannot get Twisted to work on a Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, twisted, macos-high-sierra

I am attempting to run the source code associated with the article at https://pawelmhm.github.io/python/websockets/2016/01/02/playing-with-websockets.html, but cannot get Twisted to work. I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 and Python 3.6.4 (in a virtual environment).

To create the virtual environment I used:

`python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate`

where python3 is my system installed python 3.6.4:

`$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`

I tried installing twisted using pip:

```
$ pip install twisted
Collecting twisted
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/2a/e9e4fb2e6b2f7a75577e0614926819a472934b0b85f205ba5d5d2add54d0/Twisted-18.4.0.tar.bz2 (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 1.9MB/s 
Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2 (from twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/8a/657532df378c2cd2a1fe6b12be3b4097521570769d4852ec02c24bd3594e/zope.interface-4.5.0.tar.gz (151kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 281kB/s 
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/65/48c1909d0c0aeae6c10213340ce682db01b48ea900a7d9fce7a7910ff318/constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1d/c98a587dc06e107115cf4a58b49de20b19222c83d75335a192052af4c4b7/incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/86/14c16bb98a5a3542ed8fed5d74fb064a902de3bdd98d6584b34553353c45/Automat-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1 (from twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/b6/84d0c863ff81e8e7de87cff3bd8fd8f1054c227ce09af1b679a8b17a9274/hyperlink-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->twisted) (28.8.0)
Collecting attrs>=16.1.0 (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/59/cedf87e91ed541be7957c501a92102f9cc6363c623a7666d69d51c78ac5b/attrs-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/sumit/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted) (1.11.0)
Collecting idna>=2.5 (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->twisted)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.8MB/s 
Installing collected packages: zope.interface, constantly, incremental, attrs, Automat, idna, hyperlink, twisted
  Running setup.py install for zope.interface ... done
  Running setup.py install for twisted ... done
Successfully installed Automat-0.7.0 attrs-18.1.0 constantly-15.1.0 hyperlink-18.0.0 idna-2.7 incremental-17.5.0 twisted-18.4.0 zope.interface-4.5.0
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
$ python server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twisted.web.static import File
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twisted'
```

Search on the web resulted in no useful resolution and attempts to use either `easy_install` or `brew` did not work too. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: can you do a `pip freeze | grep -i twisted` and share the results ?

Comment: Your `pip` and `python` may not correspond to one another. Try with `python -m pip install twisted` instead.

Comment: Voted to close because there's no way this can be answered (because there's too much missing information) and it's not generally useful ("how do I install Python modules on my macOS computer" does not generalize).  A different SO site might help, perhaps superuser.

Comment: @9769953, thank you, this resolved the issue. Would you like to post your comment as answer? I have added my answer but will remove it if you post yours. Appreciate your help in resolving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @9769953, that resolved the issue!

If anyone else searches for this issue (and for my future reference!), use:

`python -m pip install twisted`

I did have a virtual environment but apparently the python and pip combination was messing this up. Using `python -m pip` resolved the dependency issue.

Comment: Do a `which pip` and `which python` to see what you were using. You probably didn't initialize your virtualenv correctly, but that is hard to figure out without more details.

Comment: Yes, I tried those commands and the problem indeed was that the incorrect pip was being used. I had created the virtual env using ``python3 -m venv venv`` where python3 points to my system Python 3.6.4 installation. I expected pip to be installed with that as well, apparently it wasn't. Thanks to you I learnt the ``python -m pip`` trick today.

Comment: Hmm; curious why `pip` wasn't found in your virtual-env. Did you `source venv/bin/activate`? Is there a `pip` script in the `venv/bin/` directory?

Comment: I did source venv/bin/activate. But there is no pip in venv/bin. What could be the cause? It has only four files: ``activate activate.csh activate.fish python  python3``. All other virtual environments had pip.

Comment: Interesting. But the pip package was installed, so pip is available.

Comment: wouldn't it be named `pip3`, though?

Comment: There were only five files in the venv directory: (1) activate (2) activate.csh (3) activate.fish (4) python and (5) python3. Not sure why pip3 and a whole lot of others were not created. I have seen this kind of situation before but don't know the cause.